# Regular Expression to validate Hours and Minute using PHP Language

Tags: php, regex

I Wrote `PHP` code to check `HHMM` format using `Regular Expression`.

```
  $str = '23:40';
  if(preg_match('/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?/', $str)) {
     echo "true";
  }
    else 
    echo "false";
   }
```

It gives `true` for that given string. But, When I changed the `$str` = `'2340'`, it gives `false`.

```
     $str = '2340'; //true
     $str = '23:40'; // false
     $str = '2450' ; // false
     $str = '1261'; // false
```

These above are the results which I have expected to check from above `Regular Expression`.

Comment: and what did you expect ?

Comment: That's nice, but did you have a question?

Comment: If you want the colon to be optional just make it optional (`?`)

Comment: Don't put your question in a comment, put it in your question...

Comment: Okay, so why do you have colons in your regular expression if you don't want to match them? Why do you have the seconds check as well? Why is the `01` on the first hour group optional?

Comment: Remove `:` from the expression invalid the ` $str' = `'2450'` ; // false
     `$str` = `'1261'`; // false` conditions.

Comment: That is because you made the `01` optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the hours incorrectly. You make the first grouping of hours `0-19` optional.

Try this:

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]
```

Which will match

`0-19` or `20-23`; followed by `00-59`.

Which seems to be all you really want to match.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rH9lZ9/1

Comment: This is the answer I want. Thanks `chris85`

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help you

```
preg_match('/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$/', $str)
```

Will return true to: "2340" and more

Comment: I don not want `23:40` as valid  String . Only `2340` is valid string.

Comment: @user3789184: This is the answer of what you've asked.If you want another answer, edit yopur question and give some examples with expected result.

Comment: Why put it in a non-capturing group when it isn't being captured? A lone question mark will make it optional.

Comment: Then use:`preg_match('/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]/', $str)`

Comment: @Mikhail: Edit your answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):{0,1}[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?/', $str)) {
....
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.